# How to use Wikipedia API to get section of sidebar?

Tags: python, api

I have a command line program that gets passed in the name of a species (e.x. Fusulinida). It needs to return the plaintext of the section of the sidebar about taxonomy.

I can get upto here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Foraminifera&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&rvsection=0

But there doesn't seem to be a way to turn that into plaintext. I'm using python [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this helps:

```
import requests, json

def getTaxonomy(title):
    r = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=' + title  + '&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&rvsection=0&format=json')

    #https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&prop=revisions&format=json&rvprop=content&rvsection=0&rvcontentformat=text%2Fx-wiki&titles=Foraminifera

    a = ''
    t = json.loads(r.text)
    for i in t['query']['pages']:
        a = t['query']['pages'][ i ]['revisions'][0]['*']

    taxobox = axobox = a[a.upper().index('{{TAXOBOX') + len('{{taxobox'):]
    taxobox = taxobox[taxobox.index("\n[["):]
    taxobox = taxobox[:taxobox.index("}}")]

    taxobox = taxobox.replace('[[','')
    taxobox = taxobox.replace(']]','')
    taxobox = taxobox.replace('<br>','')
    taxobox = taxobox.replace("''",'')
    taxobox = taxobox.replace("&nbsp;",' ')

    t = []
    for i in taxobox.split("\n"):
        if len(i) > 0:
            if '|' in i:                    # for href titles
                t.append( i.split('|')[1] ) # for href titles
            else:
                t.append( i )

    return "\n".join(t)

print(getTaxonomy('Foraminifera'))
print(getTaxonomy('Fusulinida'))
```

Comment: I get an error on line 33, and I have an encode error as well. Is this written for python 2? I'll try again in a minute.

Comment: Just call the encode method for each returned string, as follows:

print(getTaxonomy('Foraminifera').encode("ascii", "replace"))

Comment: Is there a libary for this?