# Parse Wikipedia Wikitext Template Named Parameters to Extract Data from Taxobox

Tags: python, wikipedia

Using Python, I am attempting to extract data from the several "fields" of a Wikipedia Taxobox (an infobox which is usually displayed for each animal or plant species page, see for example here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okapi).

The solution provided here ([How to use Wikipedia API to get section of sidebar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33334878/how-to-use-wikipedia-api-to-get-section-of-sidebar#new-answer)) is interesting but not useful in my case, since I am interested in data from a lower taxonomic category (species).

What I want is a way (as pythonic as possible) to access every field in a Taxobox and then get the data (as a dictionary, perhaps) of interest.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

**EDIT**: Here (https://github.com/siznax/wptools) is another good solution which should be what I need, but unfortunately it is a set of command line tools (besides dependent of other command line tools available only on Linux) and not a Python library.

**EDIT2**: wptools is a (python 2,3) library now.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you please provide a sample of your desired output of the Okapi page / taxobox?

Comment: I have tried this one: https://github.com/siznax/wptools, which is really great but still not useful because it is a set of command line tools, besides depending of other command lines tools available only on Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@maurobio, @jimhark `wptools` is a python (2+3) library now. It will
give you any infobox with "box" in the name as a python `dict`, but
you probably want to use *Wikidata* (e.g. okapi
https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q82037) because infoboxen are messy (to 
say the least). If you focus on *Wikidata*, then everyone benefits, 
and `wptools` can get *Wikidata* for you too. We've recently updated wptools so that it gets ALL Wikidata by default.

You can get the infobox data in the example below in some languages, but as @biojl points out, wikitext has a different structure in different languages!

```
>>> page = wptools.page('Okapi')
>>> page.get_parse()
en.wikipedia.org (parse) Okapi
en.wikipedia.org (imageinfo) File:Okapi2.jpg
Okapi (en) data
{
  image: <list(1)> {'kind': 'parse-image', u'descriptionshorturl':...
  infobox: <dict(9)> status, status_ref, name, image, taxon, autho...
  iwlinks: <list(4)> https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Okapia_joh...
  pageid: 22709
  parsetree: <str(39115)> <root><template><title>about</title><par...
  requests: <list(2)> parse, imageinfo
  title: Okapi
  wikibase: Q82037
  wikidata_url: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q82037
  wikitext: <str(29930)> {{about|the animal}}{{good article}}{{use...
}

>>> page.data['infobox']
{'authority': '([[P.L. Sclater]], 1901)',
 'image': 'Okapi2.jpg',
 'image_caption': "An okapi at [[Disney's Animal Kingdom]] in [[Florida]].",
 'name': 'Okapi',
 'parent_authority': '[[Ray Lankester|Lankester]], 1901',
 'status': 'EN',
 'status_ref': '<ext><name>ref</name><attr> name=iucn</attr><inner>{{IUCN2008|assessor=IUCN SSC Antelope Specialist Group|year=2008|id=15188|title=Okapia johnstoni|downloaded=26 November 2013}} Database entry includes a brief justification of why this species is endangered.</inner><close>&lt;/ref&gt;</close></ext>',
 'status_system': 'IUCN3.1',
 'taxon': 'Okapia johnstoni'}
```

However, because it is structured, you can get Wikidata in many languages, e.g.

```
>>> page = wptools.page('Okapi', lang='fr')
>>> page.get_wikidata()
www.wikidata.org (wikidata) Okapi
www.wikidata.org (labels) P646|P349|P373|P685|P627|Q16521|Q7432|Q...
fr.wikipedia.org (imageinfo) File:Okapia johnstoni -Marwell Wildl...
Okapi (fr) data
{
  aliases: <list(2)> Mondonga, Okapia johnstoni
  claims: <dict(26)> P646, P181, P935, P815, P373, P1417, P685, P1...
  description: espèce de mammifères
  image: <list(2)> {'kind': 'wikidata-image', u'descriptionshortur...
  label: Okapi
  labels: <dict(31)> P646, P373, P685, P627, Q16521, Q7432, Q20415...
  modified: <dict(1)> wikidata
  pageid: 84481
  requests: <list(3)> wikidata, labels, imageinfo
  title: Okapi
  what: taxon
  wikibase: Q82037
  wikidata: <dict(26)> identifiant BioLib (P838), taxon supérieur ...
  wikidata_url: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q82037
}

>>> page.data['wikidata']
{u'carte de r\xe9partition (P181)': u'Okapi distribution.PNG',
 u'cat\xe9gorie Commons (P373)': u'Okapia johnstoni',
 u'dur\xe9e de gestation (P3063)': {u'amount': u'+14.5',
  u'lowerBound': u'+14.0',
  u'unit': u'http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q5151',
  u'upperBound': u'+15.0'},
 u'd\xe9crit par (P1343)': u'encyclop\xe9die Otto (Q2041543)',
 u'galerie Commons (P935)': u'Okapia johnstoni',
 u'identifiant ARKive (P2833)': u'okapi/okapia-johnstoni',
 u'identifiant Animal Diversity Web (P4024)': u'Okapia_johnstoni',
 u'identifiant Biblioth\xe8que nationale de la Di\xe8te (P349)': u'01092792',
 u'identifiant BioLib (P838)': u'33523',
 u'identifiant Encyclopedia of Life (P830)': u'308387',
 u'identifiant Encyclop\xe6dia Britannica en ligne (P1417)': u'animal/okapi',
 u'identifiant Fossilworks (P842)': u'149380',
 u'identifiant Freebase (P646)': u'/m/05pf4',
 u'identifiant GBIF (P846)': u'2441207',
 u'identifiant ITIS (P815)': u'625037',
 u'identifiant Mammal Species of the World (P959)': u'14200484',
 u'identifiant NCBI (P685)': u'86973',
 u'identifiant UICN (P627)': u'15188',
 u'identifiant de la Grande Encyclop\xe9die russe en ligne (P2924)': u'2290412',
 u'image (P18)': [u'Okapia johnstoni -Marwell Wildlife, Hampshire, England-8a.jpg',
  u'Okapia johnstoni1.jpg'],
 u"nature de l'\xe9l\xe9ment (P31)": u'taxon (Q16521)',
 u'nom scientifique du taxon (P225)': u'Okapia johnstoni',
 u'nom vernaculaire (P1843)': [u'Okapi', u'Okapi'],
 u'rang taxinomique (P105)': u'esp\xe8ce (Q7432)',
 u'statut de conservation UICN (P141)': u'esp\xe8ce en danger (Q11394)',
 u'taxon sup\xe9rieur (P171)': u'Okapia (Q1872039)'}
```

Don't forget that you can edit Wikidata in your own language. There are [tools](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Tools/External_tools) available to enable editing a large number of Wikidata pages.

**EDIT**: we've added a more general parser that should work (to some extent) with any infobox syntax, e.g.

```
>>> page = wptools.page('Okapi', lang='fr')
>>> page.get_parse()
fr.wikipedia.org (parse) Okapi
Okapi (fr) data
{
  infobox: <dict(2)> count, boxes
  ...
}

>>> page.data['infobox']['count']
13

>>> page.data['infobox']['boxes']
[{u'Taxobox d\xe9but': [[{'index': '1'}, 'animal'],
   [{'index': '2'}, "''Okapia johnstoni''"],
   [{'index': '3'}, 'Okapi2.jpg'],
   [{'index': '4'}, 'Okapi']]},
 {'Taxobox': [[{'index': '1'}, 'embranchement'],
   [{'index': '2'}, 'Chordata']]},
 {'Taxobox': [[{'index': '1'}, 'classe'], [{'index': '2'}, 'Mammalia']]},
 {'Taxobox': [[{'index': '1'}, 'sous-classe'], [{'index': '2'}, 'Theria']]},
 {'Taxobox': [[{'index': '1'}, 'ordre'], [{'index': '2'}, 'Artiodactyla']]},
 {'Taxobox': [[{'index': '1'}, 'famille'], [{'index': '2'}, 'Giraffidae']]},
 {'Taxobox taxon': [[{'index': '1'}, 'animal'],
   [{'index': '2'}, 'genre'],
   [{'index': '3'}, 'Okapia'],
   [{'index': '4'}, '[[Edwin Ray Lankester|Lankester]], [[1901]]']]},
 {'Taxobox taxon': [[{'index': '1'}, 'animal'],
   [{'index': '2'}, u'esp\xe8ce'],
   [{'index': '3'}, 'Okapia johnstoni'],
   [{'index': '4'}, '([[Philip Lutley Sclater|Sclater]], [[1901]])']]},
 {'Taxobox synonymes': [[{'index': '1'},
    "* ''Equus johnstoni'' <small>P.L. Sclater, 1901</small>"]]},
 {'Taxobox UICN': [[{'index': '1'}, 'EN'], [{'index': '2'}, 'A2abcd+4abcd']]},
 {u'Taxobox r\xe9partition': [[{'index': '1'}, 'Okapi map.jpg']]},
 {u'Taxobox r\xe9partition': [[{'index': '1'}, 'Okapi distribution.PNG']]},
 {'Taxobox fin': []}]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 If you can use a library to solve the problem, that would be better than the custom code I wrote in my answer. I think I came across wididata while researching my answer, but didn't see a library. @siznax, thanks for the contribution.

Comment: No problem, @jimhark. Your conversation with maurobio was a motivating  factor. Happy hacking!

Comment: This code is not working anymore. Apparently now you need to add '_' before WIKIPROPS: okapi._WIKIPROPS['P105'] = 'taxon rank', etc

Comment: What about extracting the information in other languages? For example in french the structure is not the same and it doesn't work

Comment: BTW the package was updated 2 days ago. The way you access the data has changed again. The code doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @biojl Thanks for pointing this out. Wptools is still under development. I've opened an issue for this https://github.com/siznax/wptools/issues/91

Comment: One more thing: Wptools does at least get the parsetree XML for you in all languages available. So, if you really don't want to edit Wikidata, you may have better luck parsing the XML than the wikitext in your language.

Comment: @biojl FYI: we've added a more general parsing alternative. So, this should work for you now.

Answer (score 2):

{@siznax has posted a better answer. I'm only leaving my answer here as an example of using the wiki api's and parsing the results. This would only be of practical use if a library like wptools couldn't meet your needs for some reason.}

This is a significant rewrite that includes a (more) proper parser to match the template's closing double braces '}}'. Also makes it easier to request different template names and includes a main() to allow testing from the shell / command line.

```
import sys
import re
import requests
import json

wikiApiRoot = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php'

# returns the position past the requested token or end of string if not found
def FindToken(text, token, start=0):
    pos = text.find(token, start)
    if -1 == pos:
        nextTokenPos = len(text)
    else:
        nextTokenPos = pos
    return nextTokenPos + len(token)

# Get the contents of the template as text
def GetTemplateText(wikitext, templateName):
    templateTag = '{{' + templateName

    startPos = FindToken(wikitext, templateTag)
    if (len(wikitext) <= startPos):
        # Template not found
        return None

    openCount = 1
    curPos = startPos
    nextOpenPos = FindToken(wikitext, '{{', curPos)
    nextClosePos = FindToken(wikitext, '}}', curPos)

    # scan for template's matching close braces
    while 0 < openCount:
        if nextOpenPos < nextClosePos:
            openCount += 1
            curPos = nextOpenPos
            nextOpenPos = FindToken(wikitext, '{{', curPos)
        else:
            openCount -= 1
            curPos = nextClosePos
            nextClosePos = FindToken(wikitext, '}}', curPos)

    templateText = wikitext[startPos:curPos-2]
    return templateText


def GetTemplateDict(title, templateName='Taxobox'):
    templateDict = None

    # Get data from Wikipedia:

    resp = requests.get(wikiApiRoot + '?action=query&prop=revisions&' +
        'rvprop=content&rvsection=0&format=json&redirects&titles=' +
        title)

    # Get the response text into a JSON object:

    rjson = json.loads(resp.text)

    # Pull out the text for the revision:

    wikitext = rjson['query']['pages'].values()[0]['revisions'][0]['*']

    # Parse the text for the template

    templateText = GetTemplateText(wikitext, templateName)

    if templateText:

        # Parse templateText to get named properties

        templateItemIter = re.finditer(
            r'\|\s*(\w*)\s*=\s*([^\n]*)\n',
            templateText,
            re.M)
        templateList = [item.groups([0,1]) for item in templateItemIter]
        templateDict = dict(templateList)

    return templateDict

def main():
    import argparse
    import pprint

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('title', nargs='?', default='Okapia_johnstoni', help='title of the desired article')
    parser.add_argument('template', nargs='?', default='Taxobox', help='name of the desired template')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    templateDict = GetTemplateDict(args.title, args.template)
    pprint.pprint(templateDict)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

GetTemplateDict returns a dictionary of the page's taxobox entries. For the Okapi page, this includes:

- binomial
- binomial_authority
- classis
- familia
- genus
- genus_authority
- image
- image_caption
- ordo
- phylum
- regnum
- species
- status
- status_ref
- status_system
- trend

I expect the actual items to vary by page.

The dictionary values are Wikipedia's decorated text:

```
>>> taxoDict['familia'] 
'[[Giraffidae]]'
```

So additional parsing or filtering may be desired or required.

Comment: jimhark: Thank you very much for the great answer! For years, a few humble people in the "biodiversity informatics" community (myself included) have struggled with the spiny problem of correctly parsing Wkipedia's Taxoboxes (using such languages as PHP and Java [ugh]), with meager success. Unfortunately, they didn't know Python and Stackoverflow. You have done a *big* favour to the noble cause of biodiversity conservation. Thank you very much again. Salud!

Comment: @maurobio, That is the best thanks I've ever received on StackOverflow. I appreciate it. You've motivated me to document the limitation of the regex I'm using. If you run into a problem with this solution, please share the entry that's causing the problem in a comment here and I'll try to take a look.

Comment: The solution is great and works quite well, except for a big point: it does not handle Wikipedia redirections. So, if I search using Okapi's scientific name (Okapia johnstoni) it fails (instead of redirecting to the correct page). But this can be dealt with by studying code from already existing solutions for getting data from Wikipedia, of which my favourite one is this: https://github.com/goldsmith/Wikipedia

Comment: @mauriobio, Can you give me an example page that redirects?

Comment: Sure: search Wikipedia for the scientific name of Okapi (Okapia johnstoni), it will redirect to "Okapi".

Comment: BTW, it seems the requests library does *not* handle redirections in the case of Wikipedia pages...

Comment: I just found that the answer for redirecting as as simple as that: I just need to add "&redirect" at the end of the url passed to the requests.get method call. It's as simple as that!

Comment: I thought requests had support for redirect. Thanks for finding the solution.

Comment: Indeed it has, but it does not work on Wikpedia pages. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31939197/requests-history-not-showing-all-redirects

Comment: Solution fails on such pages as those: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_manatee (where Taxobox is named "Automatic Taxobox"), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_bush_elephant (where Taxobox is named "speciesbox"), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lion and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leopard (could not see why it fails in these last two cases).

Comment: I had documented the limitations of my use of regex to extract the taxobox text. That's what you were running into on the "Lion" and "Leopard" pages. I've written a better parser to fix this problem. Your original question asked about Taxobox, not "speciesbox" or "Automatic Taxobox". Even so, I've revised the code to make it easier to use with different templates. Of course you are free to update Wikipedia, you could add taxoboxes to make its information more useful to you and the community.

Comment: You have indeed mentioned possible flaws in your otherwise fine solution; the problem of course is not with your solution, but with the Wikipedia lack of standards for infoboxes and its derivatives (like taxoboxes). Unfortunately, it is not possible to update Wikipedia pages for every species (there are lots of them!) and so the better approach is to develop the most generic and robust parser for taxoboxes. :-)